# Wrap module function and change its return

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, internationalization, wrapper

I'm using [node-i18n-iso-countries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-iso-countries) and I want to override `getNames` function that takes 2 args so it can handle a new country name that I want to add.

Currently, I'm just doing it with an `if-else` statement this way:

```
let countryName = country === 'countryName' ? 'countryName' 
: isoCountries.getName(code, lang);
```

Is there a more optimal way to do this? for example wrapping the `isoCountries.getName` function?

I'm new to TypeScript and function wrapping. So a reply with a snippet / an existing question might help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to register a locale with `registerLocale` and override the needed languages with a new country in the list of already defined countries.

### Solution 1

Do it like this by importing the JSON directly.

```js
import isoCountries, { LocaleData } from 'i18n-iso-countries'
import enJson from 'i18n-iso-countries/langs/en.json'

const localeData: LocaleData = enJson;
localeData.countries['AA'] = 'Test Country Name'
isoCountries.registerLocale(localeData)
console.log(isoCountries.getName('AA', 'en'))
// ^ Prints: Test Country Name
```

### Solution 2

If it's not possible to import a JSON, rebuild the locale data from scratch like this:

```js
import isoCountries, { LocaleData } from 'i18n-iso-countries'

const localeData: LocaleData = {
  locale: 'en',
  countries: isoCountries.getNames('en', { select: 'all' }),
};
localeData.countries['AA'] = 'Test Country Name'
isoCountries.registerLocale(localeData)
console.log(isoCountries.getName('AA', 'en'))
```

Comment: Thanks. But i'm not allowed to import JSON (pipeline won't pass when creating a merge request) in the project i'm working on, can I just do it through assigning a const to countries prop in the registerLocale and set the locale to 'es' ?

Comment: Check the 2nd proposed solution. No need to import the JSON.